# Calling SetNeedsDisplay from other class

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

Today I'm facing a new problem:

I have a ViewController (Subclass of NSView) and another class (Subclass of NSObject) which, through an IBAction, try to call back the viewController to redraw its view using SetNeedsDisplay:YES.

The method to redraw the view (ViewController.m) is:

```
- (void) redrawView {
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES] 
} 
// With an NSLog i see that the method is called !
// Instead of self i tried even an outlet connected to the custom view.
```

}

What I'm doing to call the ViewController method through my other class is:

1) `#import "ViewController.h"`

2) into the IBAction i made a new istance of ViewController as:

```
ViewController *newIstanceOfViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]
```

3) `[newIstanceOfViewController redrawView]`

The log show me that setNeedsDisplay is called but drawrect no ! Why ? I have forgotten to init or subview something ? Thanks

---

THE ORIGINAL CODE HERE (DIFFERENT NAME OF METHODS DUE TO LANGUAGE, SAME SYNTAX)

```
    //  Controller.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Controller : NSView {
    IBOutlet NSView *tastierinoView;
}
- (void) aggiornaTastierinoView;

@end


//  Controller.m

#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller

//Contatore numero volte disegno view
int contatore = 0;

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        tastierinoView = [[NSView alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) aggiornaTastierinoView { //THIS IS THE METHOD TO CALL REDRAW
    [tastierinoView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    NSLog(@"Chiamo setneedsDisplay\n\n");
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    contatore++;
    NSLog(@"La view è stata disegnata %d volte\n\n",contatore);
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    NSBezierPath* percorso = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [[NSColor cyanColor] set];

    [percorso moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(150, 150)];
    [percorso lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(250, 150)];

    [percorso setLineWidth:5.0];
    [percorso stroke];

}

@end

//  ManipolatorePin.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ManipolatorePin : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *finestraPrincipaleWindow;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *codiceTextField;
    NSArray *coordinate_x;
    NSArray *coordinate_y;
    //L'array sotto riportato serve, tramite un ciclo for, a salvare il codice pin spezzato in singoli numeri che corrisponderanno al punto.
    NSMutableArray *numeroAllaIndexArray;
}

- (IBAction)aggiornaTastierino:(id)sender;

@end

//  ManipolatorePin.m


#import "ManipolatorePin.h"
#import "Controller.h"

@implementation ManipolatorePin



- (void)awakeFromNib {
    coordinate_x = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"150",@"50",@"150",@"250",@"50",@"150",@"250",@"50",@"150",@"250", nil];
    coordinate_y = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"50",@"150",@"150",@"150",@"250",@"250",@"250",@"350",@"350",@"350", nil];


    numeroAllaIndexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Array coordinate iniziallizato.\nTest:(%@) -> deve risultare \"50\"\n\n",[coordinate_x objectAtIndex:4]);
}

- (IBAction)aggiornaTastierino:(id)sender {
    NSString *codiceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[codiceTextField stringValue]]];
    NSLog(@"codiceTextField = %@", codiceString);

    int lunghezzaCodiceString;
    NSLog(@"Il codice risulta essere composto da (%d) numeri\n\n",[codiceString length]);

    //Svuoto array
    [numeroAllaIndexArray removeAllObjects];

    for (lunghezzaCodiceString = 0; lunghezzaCodiceString < [codiceString length]; lunghezzaCodiceString++) {
        //Compilo array (Ci provo ahah)
        NSString *carattereDelCodiceStringInEsame = [[NSString alloc] init];
            carattereDelCodiceStringInEsame = [codiceString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(lunghezzaCodiceString,1)];

        NSLog(@"Aggiungo il numero (%@) all'array 'numeroAllaIndexArray'",carattereDelCodiceStringInEsame);

            [numeroAllaIndexArray addObject:carattereDelCodiceStringInEsame];
    }

    //DEBUG - DA QUI IN POI E' CANCELLABILE
    NSLog(@"\n\nCiclo for termitato\nProcesso concluso con successo\n\n\nContenuto array:");
    int conteggioArray;
    for (conteggioArray = 0; conteggioArray < [numeroAllaIndexArray count] ; conteggioArray++ ) {
        NSLog(@"index (%d) -> (%@)",conteggioArray,[numeroAllaIndexArray objectAtIndex:conteggioArray]);
        NSLog(@"\n\n");
    }
    //FINE DEBUG

    ///////////////HERE THE INSTANCE TO CALL THE CONTROLLER
    Controller *istanzaGestionaleController = [[Controller alloc] init];
    [istanzaGestionaleController aggiornaTastierinoView];


}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have two unrelated instances of ViewController. You need to call redrawView on the instance that actually has a view on the screen.

In your class (which is not the NSViewController), create a property like this:

```
  @property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) NSViewController *vc;
```

When the class is instantiated:

```
  YourClass *yourInstance = [[YourClass alloc] init];
```

assign the value of vc:

```
  yourInstance.vc = self; // self is your NSViewController instance
```

Then when you want to trigger a redraw, you pass the command to self.vc inside your other class.

Comment: Which would be the best way to fix it?

Comment: Thanks, will this work for Cocoa? I'm not on iOS. I Belive that myIstance.vc will give me a. Error